# Putting a plus symbol in the index in ConTeXt

Tags: context, context-mkiv

I tried searching the mailing list for this but maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing.

Basically, I have something I want to put in the index, but it has a plus symbol in it. ConTeXt interprets the plus symbol as a level separator, and as a result, the item I'm indexing comes out wrong.

E.g.

```
\starttext
Lorem\index{Hello + World} ipsum

\placeindex[n=1]
\stoptext
```

Produces:

[image: Old index]

But what I want (mocked up myself):

[image]

I tried manually adding the entry with `\setregisterentry` but no matter what I tried giving that command it never seemed to give me the plus symbol back.

Comment: You can use the `\textplus` command in your index entry, i.e. `\index{Hello \textplus\ World}`.

Comment: @Metafox you might want to make that an answer

Comment: @DG' That’s not necessary.

Comment: @Metafox Ok, I will cleanup my answer and the comments then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\textplus` in the index:

```
\starttext
Lorem\index[Hello + World]{Hello \textplus\ World} ipsum

\placeindex[n=1]
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I knew it would be something simple!